# Multiscroll.js inside div

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, multiscroll.js

Is it possible to "wrap" multiscroll.js inside a div and use it as a section in a one page structure (using anchors)?

Something like:

---

Header

---

Multiscroll

---

Static section

---

footer

---

Comment: Try consider creating a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it will help you as well as other SO users to provide you a better solution

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do that.

Just use fixed positioned elements outside mutiScroll wrapper.

Checkout the `fixedHeaders.html` demo available [in the plugin files](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/multiscroll.js/blob/master/examples/fixedHeaders.html).